# copying text from multiple files into corresponding location using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of files in a directory structure like

```
/tmp1/folder1/file1  
/tmp1/folder2/file2
```

Now I want to grep some lines from both these files & create/overwrite files in a path similar to the above such that lines from the file go to the respective folder

```
/tmp2/folder1/grep_from_file1  
/tmp2/folder2/grep_from_file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the "KEY" with your expect key word in grep command:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

source=/tmp1
dest=/tmp2

find $source -type f |while read file
do
  fold=${file/$source/$dest}
  fold=${fold%/*}
  name=${file##*/}
  mkdir -p $fold
  grep "KEY" $file > $fold/grep_from_$name
done
```

Comment: It's working...fold=${file/$source/$dest} cn u plz explain this hw it is working..

Comment: Read this URL: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html, in part of "Substring Replacement"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
for f in tmp1/folder1/file[12]
do
    t=tmp2/"${f#*/}"
    t="${t/\///grep_from_}"
    grep "search pttern" "$f" > "$t"
done
```

Comment: Can u please explain t=tmp2/"${f#*/}"..i am new to unix so if u cud plz

Comment: Sorry I just came back online. Hope you got your answer. Let me know if not.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should serve the purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash -f

originalFiles=("/tmp1/folder1/file1" "/tmp1/folder2/file2") # Add more

for file in "${originalFiles[@]}"
do
    newDirName=`dirname $file | sed s/tmp1/tmp2/`
    newFileName=`basename $file | sed s/^/grep_from_/`
    mkdir -p $newDirName
    grep "text_to_grep" $file > $newDirName/$newFileName
done
```